# Unity3D install mishab on Ubuntu; 2 installs taking space

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine

I accidentally installed Unity3D as root. I wasn't able to find the install as root in nautilus.
Eventually I installed it again on the same spot I originally selected (but where it didn't show up) as user, and now it's fine.
However, I still have 3GB being taken up by a ghost root Unity install.
How can I fix this?

My version is: Unity-2017.3.0f1

Comment: its normal to install using sudo xxxx which does the install as root  ... crtl + alt + t  will open up a terminal window ... from there you can discover where dir or files live

Comment: Yes, but the directory is missing and 3GB is missing from my HDD.